# Powershell Error

Tags: powershell, csv

I am getting the below error when I run my PowerShell Code. I cannot figure it out at all. I am not sure if it has to do with the name of my file location or not.

```
Import-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "CSV" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."
At line:4 char:60
+ ... GroupList = Import-CSV C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Te ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Script source:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$GroupList = Import-CSV C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Test2-TestOutput1.csv -header GroupName,Domain | Select GroupName,Domain

$Table = @()
$Record = @{}

foreach ($Group in $GroupList) {    
If ($Group.Domain -Eq "a") {$DomainPath = "a.corp"}
If ($Group.Domain -Eq "x") {$DomainPath = "x.corp"}
If ($Group.Domain -Eq "y") {$DomainPath = "y.com"}
If ($Group.Domain -Eq "b") {$DomainPath = "b.com"}

#Get-ADGroupMember command with -Recursive switch includes only object type users with members of nested groups
$GroupMembership = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group.GroupName -Server $DomainPath -Recursive | select SamAccountName, Name, objectClass, distinguishedname

#Get-ADGroupMember command without -Recursive switch includes both User and Group objects but no membership of nested groups
#$GroupMembership = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group.GroupName -Server $DomainPath | select SamAccountName, Name, objectClass, distinguishedname

foreach ($GroupMember in $GroupMembership) {
    $Record."Account Name" = $GroupMember.samaccountname
    $Record."Full Name" = $GroupMember.name
    $Record."ObjectClass" = $GroupMember.objectClass
    $Record."Object DistinguishedName" = $GroupMember.DistinguishedName
    $Record."Group Name" = $Group.GroupName
    $Record."Group Domain" = $Group.Domain
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
    $Table += $objrecord
}
}

 $Table | export-csv "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)-ADGroupMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: When importing make sure your path is enclosed in quotation marks. `Import-CSV C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Test2-TestOutput1.csv` Your import path is missing quotes and results in nothing being loaded.

Comment: flagged for closure/typo

Comment: @JasonSnell Not entirely correct.  It's binding `CSV` to the Delimiter positional argument, and the path is only being interpreted as `C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell` So it's trying to find a file called `Powershell` and delimit the entries with `CSV` hah

Comment: Please ask more concise questions! Everything after line 4 is completely superfluous, why clog StackOverflow with it?

Comment: @HansLub It might help to post an example of more concise, otherwise your statement is superfluous.  e.g. post the error, post the line where the error is from.

Comment: Have you checked what @JasonSnell was telling? Add the quotes then it wont look for the powershell folder. since the path is having space it considered the last leaf(\Powershell) as the end path and started splitting that with the delimiter.change it with double quotes or single quotes.Remove that obfuscation and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a path (file or folder name) that contains white space, you need to quote it:

```
$GroupList = Import-CSV "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Test2-TestOutput1.csv" -header GroupName,Domain | Select GroupName,Domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your argument, otherwise spaces are interpreted as positional arguments.

```
$GroupList = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\Powershell CSV Test\Test2-TestOutput1.csv' -header GroupName,Domain | Select GroupName,Domain
```